# Open Text File Using Variable in Filename

Tags: perl

I am trying to open a text file in my perl script. Part of the filename contains the date in YYYYMMDD format, which changes. I am having problems building the file path correctly.

**Full Filename:**

```
abc_20160825_filename.txt
```

**Code:**

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);
$currdate = strftime "%Y%m%d\n", localtime;

$filename = 'directory/', $currdate '_filename.txt';

open(FILE, $filename) or die "Cant find file";
```

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: I have defined a variable that result in a date string (ex. 20160825). I am trying to then substitute this into the filename for a text file that has the 20160825 date text and then open the file in the perl script.

Comment: Yes that i understand. But i do not understand what your Problem is

Comment: You say you want to create a file called `abc_20160825_filename.txt`, but your Perl code (which won't even compile) looks like it's trying to create `directory/20160825_filename.txt`. Which is it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things, you had `\n` in your strftime call, which appends a new line. You don't want this. You're not concatenating your string properly here:

```
$filename = 'directory/', $currdate '_filename.txt';
```

it's `.` not `,`, and you don't have one between the variable and `_filename.txt`. The example below includes `use strict; use warnings;` and does what you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $currdate = strftime( "%Y%m%d", localtime );
my $filename = 'directory/' . $currdate . '_filename.txt';
print $filename;
```

Edit, also use 3 argument [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), and get it to tell you why it failed:

```
open(FILE,'<', $filename) or die "Cant find file $!\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to create a file called `abc_20160825_filename.txt`, but your Perl code (which won't even compile) looks like it's trying to create `directory/20160825_filename.txt`. Which is it please?

I suggest that you use the [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module together with `sprintf`. This example program generates both variations, and I hope it is easy to see how you could modify it

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece 'localtime';

{
    my $filename = sprintf
            'abc_%s_filename.txt',
            localtime->strftime('%Y%m%d');

    say $filename;
}

{
    my $filename = sprintf
            'directory/%s_filename.txt',
            localtime->strftime('%Y%m%d');

    say $filename;
}
```

#### output

```
abc_20160825_filename.txt
directory/20160825_filename.txt
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm using PHP, but I think its similar to Perl.

```
$currdate = strftime "%Y%m%d\n", localtime;
$filename = "directory/$currdate_filename.txt";
```

All you have done wrong is the syntax to building the string.

Another way to build a string is like this:

```
$currdate = strftime "%Y%m%d\n", localtime;
$filename = "directory/" . $currdate . "_filename.txt";
```

Please check whether Perl uses `.` like PHP, or `+` like JavaScript to chain separate text elements.

Comment: you've got a newline appended to `$currdate` which is going to be used as a part of a file name. Single quotes for strings unless you're doing interpolation

Comment: ***Please test your solutions***. You are publishing to the entire world what is supposed to be a solution to the OP's problem, yet you don't even test what you are proposing! Using your code, perl will try to interpolate the variable `$currdate_filename`, which doesn't exist. It will generate the warning message `Use of uninitialized value $currdate_filename in concatenation (.) or string` and set `$filename` top `directory/.txt`.